# For no Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Estou com um problema da seguinte forma:
Eu preciso criar uma tabela para impressão, onde ela será preenchida manualmente, e para isso, preciso gerar linhas de acordo com um número que vou repassar por parâmetro.
Preciso saber como faço um for com isso dentro do jasper reports.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Você sabe quantas colunas haverão? Pois poderia criar somente as colunas na aba de header, e somente uma linha na aba detail.. Que é onde repetiria.. E no back do java retornaria uma lista com a mesma quantidade de posições que tua tabela teria de linhas e o Jasper percorreria essa lista preenchendo com linhas vazias..